# Find index of a specific character in a string then parse the string

Tags: string, parsing, vbscript

I have strings which looks like this `[NAME LASTNAME/NAME.LAST@emailaddress/123456678]`. What I want to do is parse strings which have the same format as shown above so I only get `NAME LASTNAME`. My psuedo idea is find the index of the first instance of `/`, then strip from index `1` to that index of `/` we found. I want this as a VBScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way should work. You can also `Split()` your string on `/` and just grab the first element of the resulting array:

```
Const SOME_STRING = "John Doe/John.Doe@example.com/12345678"

WScript.Echo Split(SOME_STRING, "/")(0)
```

Output:

```
John Doe
```

**Edit**, with respect to comments.

If your string contains the `[`, you can still `Split()`. Just use `Mid()` to grab the first element starting at character position 2:

```
Const SOME_STRING = "[John Doe/John.Doe@example.com/12345678]"

WScript.Echo Mid(Split(SOME_STRING, "/")(0), 2)
```

Comment: The strings actually includes the `[` and `]` so would I need to do it in two steps cause then if I do it like above, it would still include the `[` in the front?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good here, you should also need to grab index for "[".This will make script robust and flexible here.Below code will always return strings placed between first occurrence of "[" and "/".

```
var = "[John Doe/John.Doe@example.com/12345678]"
WScript.Echo Mid(var, (InStr(var,"[")+1),InStr(var,"/")-InStr(var,"[")-1)
```